# Differential equation with an integral

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, definite-integrals

I need to find function $f$ (the book doesn't specify whether $f(x)$ or $f(t)$) that satisfies the following equation:

$$\int_0^xf(t)\,dt= {2 \over 3}xf(x)$$

Can anyone please tell me how this problem can be solved?

I would be very grateful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Differentiate both sides using the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus and the Product Rule (do you know these theorems?):
$$f(x)=\frac{2}{3}(f(x)+xf'(x)) \implies \frac{1}{3}f(x)=\frac{2}{3}xf'(x) \implies \frac{1}{2x}=\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}$$
Integrating, $$\ln(f(x))=\frac{1}{2}\ln(x)+C \implies f(x)=Ax^{1/2}$$
Where $C$ and $A$ are arbitrary constants depending on initial conditions. If you are unfamiliar with the integration of the LHS, differentiate $\ln(f(x))$ with the chain rule.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** Differentiate the equation (why can you differentiate the RHS?) to get an ordinary differential equation. Use the fundamental theorem of calculus to differentiate the LHS.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: Expanding on Git Gud, show that
$$
f = C \sqrt{x}$$